# How to go back to previous view controller using custom back button?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to iOS development. I am going to next screen using following statement.

`locationViewController = [[LocationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LocationViewController" bundle:nil];`

`[navigationController pushViewController:locationViewController animated:YES];`

Now I want to go back to previous screen by tapping on custom back button on the top bar of the current screen.

Comment: +1 Cheers!!! 
@Bharat Dodeja

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use this:

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

For home button:

```
NSArray *viewContrlls=[[self navigationController] viewControllers];
for( int i=0;i<[ viewContrlls count];i++)
{
    id obj=[viewContrlls objectAtIndex:i];
    if([obj isKindOfClass:[Rate_O_MeterViewController class]])
    {
        [[self navigationController] popToViewController:obj animated:YES];
        return;
    }
}
```

in place of Rate_O_MeterViewController give your controller name...add it in action of home button.

Comment: thanks for the help @Vishal. One more question. I have another button on the right side of top bar. By clicking on that button, it should navigate to home screen(i.e first screen of the app).

Comment: [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];...use this line in your action.

Comment: It went to root `viewcontroller`, but I forgot to tell you that I have splash screen as the first `viewcontroller`. sorry it was my bad. The second `viewcontroller` is home screen. Can I remove splash screen `viewcontroller` from the stack aftet coming to home screen for the first time? So that on the root, there will be home screen's `viewcontroller`.

Comment: Currently your button are in which controller third controller?

Comment: If you are want to go to one screen back then use first option that mention in answer...

Comment: Actually, I have nested screens till 3rd or 4th level. Back and Home buttons are common to all these screen.

Comment: You can also use this method to pop to any particular view:[self.navigationController popToViewController:YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER> animated:YES]

Comment: @Vishal It solved my issue. Thanks all for the help, appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Back button:

```
    UIBarButtonItem * backButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(goBack:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=backButton;
```

And write a function:

```
-(void)goBack:(id)sender
 {
      [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

appDelegate.m   - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
//-----------navigation view--------------
UINavigationController *navHomeController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navHomeController;
```